# Date picker edit option is not available

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

DateTimeField is coming from this package datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0 and datepickerdialog from flutter package only

Date picker edit option is not available.

I am able to enter date via calender pick but edit option is disable by default.

```dart
DateTimeField(
  readOnly: true,
  controller: dobController,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Enter date of birth',
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.date_range,
        color: Colors.grey,
      )),
  onSaved: (DateTime? val) {
    dobDate = val;
  //   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(emailFocus);

  },
  format: format,
  resetIcon: null,
  style: AppUtils.textFieldStyle(),
  showCursor: false,
  onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return DatePickerDialog(
            initialDate: currentValue ?? initialDate,
            firstDate: DateTime(1900),
            initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.input,
            lastDate: initialDate,
        );
      },
    );
  }),
```

See my screenshot.

[image: screenshot].

Comment: I'm not familiar with `DateTimeField` but I can imagine that it's because of `readOnly: true` that you have in there

Comment: even after removing it its not working as expected

Comment: Indicate what library are you using. Where are these `DatePickerDialog` and `DateTimeField` classes defined.

Comment: DateTimeField is coming from this package datetime_picker_formfield: ^2.0.0 and datepickerdialog from flutter package only

Comment: Please include that information in you question

Answer (score 0):

Here is working solution of date picker in inputfield:

```
TextFormField(
                                  readOnly: true,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
                                  autovalidateMode:
                                      AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                                  autofocus: false,
                                 
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    labelText: 'Date: ',
                                    labelStyle: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                        color: Color(0xff7C878C),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                 ,
                                 
                               
                                  ),
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    DateTime? pickdate =
                                        await showDatePicker(
                                      context: context,
                                      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                                      firstDate: DateTime(1950),
                                      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
                                    );
                                    if (pickdate != null) {
                                      setState(() {
                                        _dateTextController.text =
                                            DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                                                .format(pickdate);
                                        selectedDate = pickdate;
                                      });
                                    }
                                  },
                                  controller: _dateTextController,
                                  validator: (value) {
                                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                      return 'Please Enter Date';
                                    }
                                    return null;
                                  },
                                ),
```